# How to become a non-root user while using (delegate_to) on ansbile playbook?

Tags: ansible

In this ansible-playbook, I am delegating a task to a server to run as a non-root user but everytime it runs as a root user. Can you help me what i am doing wrong here?

```
- name: Set access to starz app
become: yes
become_user: starz
command: giveaccess {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ access_app_port }}
delegate_to: "{{starz_central_node}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by inserting "remote_user" field instead of "become_user". I still don't understand why become_user doesnt work when delegate_to field is present.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `become_method: doas`.

Comment: This didn't work :(

Comment: it says.. /bin/sh doas : command not found